# localStorage/localForage issue after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, localforage

I am working with localForage and I have one good thing and another very bad that I've been trying to resolve the last 2 hours, I thought it was easier but that's why I am here.

I have an array named `sports` with the option to checked or unchecked them, once you unchecked or `checked = false` -whatever you want to call it- those items are saved in a DB, but they supposed to be saved in a localForage while the user is within the session first.

**The good part:**
if you `checked = false` any item on the array and log out, and them log in, the item you set unchecked is still there, that part is working great.

**The bad part:**
if you `checked = false` any item on the array and you refresh the page, the item `checked = false` return back to `checked = true`.

So it means that after refreshing the page, the data is not persisting, only if you log out and log in again.

I am using something named `forceTrip` which you will see in the code below.

Everything is related to the service, look

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('SportsFactory', function($http, $q, AuthFactory,
           LocalForageFactory, LeaguesFactory, CONSTANT_VARS) {
    return {
      getSports: function(customer, forceTrip) {
        forceTrip = forceTrip || false;
        var defer = $q.defer(),
        _this = this;

        if (forceTrip) {
         LocalForageFactory.remove(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS)
        }

        LocalForageFactory.retrieve(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS)

              $http.get(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/lines/sports/' + customer.agent)
                .success(function(sports) {
                  sports = _.sortBy(sports, function(sport) {
                    return sport.priority;
                  });

          //HERE I CALL GETSPORTCHECKED();
                  _this.getSportChecked(customer).then(function(sportChecked) {
                    var sportIds = _.pluck(sports, 'id'),
                        intersectedSports = _.intersection(sportIds, sportChecked.sport);
                    if (sports.length) {
                      sports = _.map(sports, function(sport) {
                        sport.checked = !_.includes(intersectedSports, sport.id);
                        return sport;
                      });
                    }
                  });
                  LocalForageFactory.set(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS, sports);
                  defer.resolve(sports);
                })
                .error(function(err) {
                  defer.reject(err);
                });
            }
          });
        return defer.promise;
      },

      setSportChecked: function(params) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.post(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/sports/checked', params)
        .success(function(sportChecked) {
            LocalForageFactory.remove(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_CHECKED, params);
            defer.resolve(sportChecked);
          })
          .error(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            defer.reject(err);
          });
        return defer.promise;
      },

      getSportChecked: function(customer, forceTrip) {
        forceTrip = forceTrip || false;
        var defer = $q.defer(),
            user,
            rejection = function(err) {
              defer.reject(err);
            };

        if (forceTrip) {
          LocalForageFactory.remove(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_CHECKED);
        }
        LocalForageFactory.retrieve(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_CHECKED)
          .then(function(sportChecked) {
            user = customer.customer;
              $http.get(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/sports/getChecked/' + user)
              .success(function(sportChecked) {
                LocalForageFactory.set(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_CHECKED, sportChecked);
                defer.resolve(sportChecked);
              })
              .error(rejection);
            }
          }, rejection);
        return defer.promise;
      }

  };    
});
```

The function `setSportChecked` performs a post request once you `checked = false` any of the items, and `getSportChecked` makes the get request to get `checked = false` items, and in `getSports` you can see that I am calling `_this.getSportChecked(customer)`, so what do you think I can do here?